# How can I work out time elapsed for a bot uptime command? python

Tags: python, time, chatbot, twitch

I would like to have a bot uptime command, the code below is what im aiming for, however after 12am it will convert to -1day, this is extremely irritating when the bot is going to be running for more than a day at a time.

Im not sure whats causing this so any info would be massive help.

```
from datetime import datetime
import os
import time

folder = r"C:\Users\Ryan Mclaughlin\PycharmProjects\Snappingbot-V2\SnappingbotV2\text files"
filename = "uptime.txt"
fp = os.path.join(folder, filename)

with open(fp, "w") as f:
    f.writelines(datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')) # on startup of bot write the time in a file
file = open(fp)

startup_time = (file.readline())  # reads the startup time

print(startup_time)
time.sleep(10)
time_now = datetime.now().time().strftime('%H:%M:%S')  # finds time now
print(time_now)

FMT = '%H:%M:%S'
tdelta = datetime.strptime(time_now, FMT) - datetime.strptime(startup_time,FMT)  # calculates the difference between the startup time and now
print(tdelta)
```

Comment: Why are you not using the date parts? Wouldn't the calculation be simpler if you get the delta of two datetime objects?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how these time modules work to be honest  Could you give me an explanation on what or why you would get the delta of the datetime objects and how I could approach this?